# How can I prevent tomcat server from closing when I logoff?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I am using tomcat and jenkins in a windows 7 remote machine (using it like a server). But when I log off from remote machine the tomcat server/jenkins will close.

Is there any way that I can make tomcat keep running, even if log I off from the remote machine?

Comment: Are you running Jenkins from command prompt?

Comment: run it as a service, instead of as a front-end process

Comment: I am invoking jenkins by running the tomcat (kept jenkins.war in tomcat) through command promt. So running jenkins as a service solvs the prob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run Jenkins from command prompt, it will terminate the session as soon as you log off. To avoid this from happening, you need to install Jenkins as a service. This way, Jenkins will automatically start even when the server reboots.

You can refer the *official* link for step-by-step instruction on how to install Jenkins as a service:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Comment: I am invoking jenkins by running the tomcat (kept jenkins.war in tomcat) through command promt. So running jenkins as a service solvs the prob?

Comment: @Bharath: Yes. On Windows, when you are running Jenkins through Tomcat (or any other container) using command prompt, it will always terminate once you log off. The solution is to install Jenkins as a service. Just follow the steps in the link i have given above and your issue will be solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll change the set up and let you know the outcome